# Javascript - Error when calling "apply" on cloned native function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to clone the function `indexedDB.cmp` in Chrome, then replace `indexedDB.cmp` with a new function. The new function logs the passed arguments using `console.log`, then calls the cloned function using `apply`. However, I keep getting the error "Illegal Invocation" when I use `apply`. I only need this to work on Google Chrome. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function init() {
    var i = indexedDB;
    i.cmp2 = i.cmp.bind({});
    i.cmp = function(...a) {
        console.log("CMP call!",a);
        return i.cmp2.apply(null,a);
    };
}
init();
indexedDB.cmp("/testFolder",3);
```

Comment: Since you're already using spread syntax, why not invoke the function with spread instead of apply?

Comment: Thank you! I changed `i.cmp.bind({})` to `i.cmp.bind(i)`, tried your suggestion, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

"Since you're already using spread syntax, why not invoke the function with spread instead of apply? – Mikael Lennholm"

I also changed `i.cmp.bind({})` to `i.cmp.bind(i)`.